# Accessing the JDBC ResultSet concurrently in Spring

Tags: spring, jdbc, concurrency, thread-safety, dao

I am processing a large amount of data in a Spring JDBC DAO. The DAO directly returns an Iterator over the objects which operates on a bounded *BlockingQueue* using *take()* while the retrieval operation is happening in a separate thread (using an *ExecutorService*).

Inside this thread I see the following behaviour: the retrieval works but certain calls to the *ResultSet* are causing the call to hang. These calls are

- *isClosed()* and
- *isLast()*

but not

- *isAfterLast()* or
- *isBeforeFirst()* or
- *isFirst()*

Obviously I need to know what the last element is (in order to insert a special element into the blocking queue that yields false in the iterators hasNext() method). I could work around it by finding out the number of rows in the *ResultSet* before putting objects into the *BlockingQueue* but this feels a bit clumsy. Is there a thread-safe way to work with ResultSets?

Switching to a multi-threaded datasource (I tested C3POs *ComboPooledDataSource*) does not seem to help.

Note: this issue was first (incorrectly) identified by me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341254/spring-jdbc-support-and-large-dataset)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct solution is to set an appropriate *ResultSet* type. The default *"TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY"* is [not supported](http://www.oracle.com/technology/docs/tech/java/sqlj_jdbc/doc_library/javadoc/oracle.jdbc.driver.oracleresultset.html#isLast()) by *isLast()*. The type of *ResultSet* can be set by using a *PreparedStatementCreator* instead of an SQL string for e.g. *query()* calls to a *JdbcTemplate*. Such instances are acquired through a *PreparedStatementCreatorFactory*. On such a factory the type of the *ResultSet* (e.g. *"TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE"*) can be set.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that `java.sql.ResultSet` is thread-safe, although admittedly this is not actually  mentioned in the javadoc. I wouldn't be at all surprised if calling methods on a `ResultSet` from different threads causes those method calls to hang.

As an alternative, I suggest having your retrieval thread as the only user of the `ResultSet`, pulling the rows off and then dumping the data itself on to your `BlockingQueue`. It then becomes trivial to detect the end of the result set and put your EOF marker on the queue.

The generally preferred mechanism in JDBC for iterating over very large result sets is to use the `fetchSize` property of `java.sql.Statement`, although this is highly dependent on the database and JDBC driver. I know that the Oracle driver honours this setting, but not sure about others. If the driver decides that it needs to fetch the whole result set into memory before giving you the first row, then no matter what you do you won't be able to process the first rows while fetching the next ones.

Comment: I am currently using a fetch size. It's the (relativly) lower processing speed of the data consumers that require the use of blocking queues. AFAIK the DAO in question currently IS the only user of the ResultSet. With the explicit row counting workaround I might as well leave things be as they are and document the ResultSet behaviour accordingly.

Comment: Yes, but is the DAO being accessed from multiple threads, all of which are operating on the same ResultSet?

Comment: No, the ResultSet should be accessed only by one Thread. I will have to investigate this further.