# JdbcRowSet: very large result overflows heap despite trying to read limited # of rows at a time

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

I'm using a `JdbcRowSet` to retrieve a data set that could be very large (1M+ rows returned).

Because the result set could be so large I do not wish to hold it in memory. I wish to use the `JdbcRowSet` as a *connected* `RowSet` and fetch rows from the database as needed, rather than using the `JdbcRowSet` as a disconnected `RowSet` which would hold all rows in memory.

Unfortunately when using the below code to initialize my `JdbcRowSet`, the entire `RowSet` is pulled into the heap, which causes `OutOfMemoryError`s and takes the application down.

How can I prevent the JDBC driver or `JdbcRowSet` from forcibly loading the entire result set into memory, but rather only fetching (per the example below) 100 rows into memory at a time?

I am using Spring to wire the application generally, and Spring JDBC templates throughout my data layer.  Database is Oracle 11g.

```
JdbcRowSet jdbcRowSet = new com.sun.rowset.JdbcRowSetImpl(jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection());
jdbcRowSet.setConcurrency(ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
jdbcRowSet.setReadOnly(true);
jdbcRowSet.setCommand(sql);
jdbcRowSet.setString(1, value);
jdbcRowSet.execute();
jdbcRowSet.setFetchDirection(ResultSet.FETCH_FORWARD);
jdbcRowSet.setFetchSize(100);
```

(please don't encourage me to change my query so that fewer rows are returned; I assure you that this is a business requirement, is non-optional, etc)

Comment: If you need to process a query of that size, you should use a plain `ResultSet`, not a `RowSet`.

Comment: @Andreas I am beginning to think that you're right, but I think the question is still valid: How do you coerce this construct to only pull a limited number of rows from the query, rather than pulling everything in and blowing the heap up?

Comment: you can use jdbcTemplate.query() variant with RowCallbackHandler or ResultSetExtractor. It will not load all resultset into memory.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341254/spring-jdbc-support-and-large-dataset?rq=1 is actually pretty helpful here.  The solution I ended up with was as @Andreas suggested, not using `RowSet` at all, but rather a vanilla `ResultSet`.