# How to read all rows from huge table?

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

I have a problem with processing all rows from database (PostgreSQL). I get an error: `org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ran out of memory retrieving query results.` I think that I need to read all rows in small pieces, but it doesn't work - it reads only 100 rows (code below). How to do that?

```
    int i = 0;      
    Statement s = connection.createStatement();
    s.setMaxRows(100); // bacause of: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Ran out of memory retrieving query results.
    ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from " + tabName);      
    for (;;) {
        while (rs.next()) {
            i++;
            // do something...
        }
        if ((s.getMoreResults() == false) && (s.getUpdateCount() == -1)) {
            break;
        }           
    }
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Use [a CURSOR in PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-declare.html) or [let the JDBC-driver handle this for you](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#fetchsize-example).

LIMIT and OFFSET will get slow when handling large datasets.

Comment: Try this one: http://jdbc.postgresql.org//documentation/head/query.html#fetchsize-example

Answer (score 71):

The short version is, call `stmt.setFetchSize(50);` and `conn.setAutoCommit(false);` to avoid reading the entire `ResultSet` into memory.

Here's what the [docs](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/head/query.html#query-with-cursor) say:

> **Getting results based on a cursor**
>
> By default the driver collects all the results for the query at once.
>   This can be inconvenient for large data sets so the JDBC driver
>   provides a means of basing a ResultSet on a database cursor and only
>   fetching a small number of rows.
>
> A small number of rows are cached on the client side of the connection
>   and when exhausted the next block of rows is retrieved by
>   repositioning the cursor.
>
> Note:
>
> - Cursor based ResultSets cannot be    used in all situations. There a    number of restrictions which will    make the driver silently
>     fall back to    fetching the whole ResultSet at once.
> - The connection to the server must be    using the V3 protocol. This is the    default for (and is only supported    by) server versions
>     7.4 and later.-
> - The Connection must not be in    autocommit mode. The backend closes    cursors at the end of transactions,    so in autocommit mode
>     the backend    will have closed the cursor before    anything can be
>     fetched from it.-
> - The Statement must be created with a    ResultSet type of    ResultSet.TYPE_FORWARD_ONLY. This is    the default, so no code will
>     need to    be rewritten to take advantage of    this, but it also
>     means that you    cannot scroll backwards or otherwise    jump around
>     in the ResultSet.-
> - The query given must be a single statement, not multiple statements strung together with semicolons.

**Example 5.2. Setting fetch size to turn cursors on and off.**

Changing code to cursor mode is as simple as setting the fetch size of the Statement to the appropriate size. Setting the fetch size back to 0 will cause all rows to be cached (the default behaviour).

```
// make sure autocommit is off
conn.setAutoCommit(false);
Statement st = conn.createStatement();

// Turn use of the cursor on.
st.setFetchSize(50);
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable");
while (rs.next()) {
   System.out.print("a row was returned.");
}
rs.close();

// Turn the cursor off.
st.setFetchSize(0);
rs = st.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM mytable");
while (rs.next()) {
   System.out.print("many rows were returned.");
}
rs.close();

// Close the statement.
st.close();
```

---

Comment: Is there any disadvantage to this? Should I just enable it for all queries (from the wording in the doc it sounds superior in all cases; if you're reading large tables it's better and if you're reading small tables it doesn't matter)

Answer (score 7):

So it turns out that the crux of the problem is that by default, Postgres starts in "autoCommit" mode, and also it needs/uses cursors to be able to "page" through data (ex: read the first 10K results, then the next, then the next), however cursors can only exist within a transaction.  So the default is to read all rows, always, into RAM, and then allow your program to start processing "the first result row, then the second" after it has all arrived, for two reasons, it's not in a transaction (so cursors don't work), and also a fetch size hasn't been set.

So how the `psql` command line tool achieves batched response (its `FETCH_COUNT` setting) for queries, is to "wrap" its select queries within a short-term transaction (if a transaction isn't yet open), so that cursors can work.  You can do something like that also with JDBC:

```
  static void readLargeQueryInChunksJdbcWay(Connection conn, String originalQuery, int fetchCount, ConsumerWithException<ResultSet, SQLException> consumer) throws SQLException {
    boolean originalAutoCommit = conn.getAutoCommit();
    if (originalAutoCommit) {
      conn.setAutoCommit(false); // start temp transaction
    }
    try (Statement statement = conn.createStatement()) {
      statement.setFetchSize(fetchCount);
      ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery(originalQuery);
      while (rs.next()) {
        consumer.accept(rs); // or just do you work here
      }
    } finally {
      if (originalAutoCommit) {
        conn.setAutoCommit(true); // reset it, also ends (commits) temp transaction
      }
    }
  }
  @FunctionalInterface
  public interface ConsumerWithException<T, E extends Exception> {
    void accept(T t) throws E;
  }
```

This gives the benefit of requiring less RAM, and, in my results, seemed to run overall faster, even if you don't need to save the RAM.  Weird. It also gives the benefit that your processing of the first row "starts faster" (since it process it a page at a time).

And here's how to do it the "raw postgres cursor" way, along with full demo [code](https://gist.github.com/rdp/aff8e897cb3f2379d2ede80793781c81), though in my experiments it seemed the JDBC way, above, was slightly faster for whatever reason.

Another option would be to have `autoCommit` mode off, everywhere, though you still have to always manually specify a fetchSize for each new Statement (or you can set a default fetch size in the URL string).

Answer (score 2):

I think your question is similar to this thread: [JDBC Pagination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771439/jdbc-pagination) which contains solutions for your need.

In particular, for PostgreSQL, you can use the LIMIT and OFFSET keywords in your request: http://www.petefreitag.com/item/451.cfm

PS: In Java code, I suggest you to use PreparedStatement instead of simple Statements: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html

Comment: Just use Spring, practically no need to ever code against the JDK classes - http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/jdbc.html

Comment: LIMIT and OFFSET don't scale well for very large resultsets :\

Answer (score 0):

I did it like below. Not the best way i think, but it works :)

```
    Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://....");
    PreparedStatement s = c.prepareStatement("select * from " + tabName + " where id > ? order by id");
    s.setMaxRows(100);
    int lastId = 0;
    for (;;) {
        s.setInt(1, lastId);
        ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery();

        int lastIdBefore = lastId;
        while (rs.next()) {
            lastId = Integer.parseInt(rs.getObject(1).toString());
            // ...
        }

        if (lastIdBefore == lastId) {
            break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

At lest in my case the problem was on the client that tries to fetch the results.

Wanted to get a .csv with ALL the results.

I found the solution by using

```
psql -U postgres -d dbname  -c "COPY (SELECT * FROM T) TO STDOUT WITH DELIMITER ','"
```

(where dbname the name of the db...) and redirecting to a file.