# OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, mysql, csv, out-of-memory

I'm having a problem with a java OutOfMemoryError. The program basically looks at mysql tables that are running on mysql workbench, and queries them to get out certain information, and then puts them in CSV files.

The program works just fine with a smaller data set, but once I use a larger data set (hours of logging information as opposed to perhaps 40 minutes) I get this error, which to me says that the problem comes from having a huge data set and the information not being handled too well by the program. Or it not being possible to handle this amount of data in the way that I have.

Setting Java VM arguments to -xmx1024m worked for a slightly larger data set but i need it to handle even bigger ones but it gives the error.

Here is the method which I am quite sure is the cause of the program somewhere:

```
// CSV is csvwriter (external lib), sment are Statements, rs is a ResultSet
public void pidsforlog() throws IOException
{
    String[] procs;
    int count = 0;
    String temp = "";

    System.out.println("Commence getting PID's out of Log");
    try {
        sment = con.createStatement();
        sment2 = con.createStatement();
        String query1a = "SELECT * FROM log, cpuinfo, memoryinfo";
        rs = sment.executeQuery(query1a);
        procs = new String[countThrough(rs)];

        // SIMPLY GETS UNIQUE PROCESSES OUT OF TABLES AND STORES IN ARRAY
        while (rs.next()) {
            temp = rs.getString("Process");

            if(Arrays.asList(procs).contains(temp)) {
            } else {
                procs[count] = temp;
                count++;
            }
        }

        // BELIEVE THE PROBLEM LIES BELOW HERE. SIZE OF THE RESULTSET TOO BIG?
        for(int i = 0; i < procs.length; i++) {
            if(procs[i] == null) {
            } else {
                String query = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM log, cpuinfo, memoryinfo WHERE log.Process = " + "'" + procs[i] + "'" + " AND cpuinfo.Process = " + "'" + procs[i] + "'" + " AND memoryinfo.Process = " + "'" + procs[i] + "'  AND log.Timestamp = cpuinfo.Timestamp = memoryinfo.Timestamp";
                System.out.println(query);
                rs = sment.executeQuery(query);

                writer = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter(procs[i] + ".csv"), ',');
                writer.writeAll(rs, true);
                writer.flush();
            }
        }
        writer.close();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        notify("Error pidslog", e);
    }
}; // end of method
```

Please feel free to ask if you want source code or more information as I'm desperate to get this fixed!

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to use a [profiler](http://profiler.netbeans.org/)?

Comment: Can't you stream the results from the database into the file without having everything at once in memory?

Comment: `writer.close()` i.o. flush (inside the loop). Many opportunities to improve in the code; hire a programmer.

Answer (score 2):

`SELECT * FROM log, cpuinfo, memoryinfo` will sure give a huge result set. It will give a cartesian product of all rows in all 3 tables.

Without seeing the table structure (or knowing the desired result) it's hard to pinpoint a solution, but I suspect that you either want some kind of join conditions to limit the result set, or use a `UNION` a'la;

```
SELECT Process FROM log
UNION
SELECT Process FROM cpuinfo
UNION
SELECT Process FROM memoryinfo
```

...which will just give you all distinct values for `Process` in all 3 tables.

Your second SQL statement also looks a bit strange;

```
SELECT DISTINCT * 
FROM log, cpuinfo, memoryinfo 
WHERE log.Process = @param1  
  AND cpuinfo.Process = @param1
  AND memoryinfo.Process = @param1
  AND log.Timestamp = cpuinfo.Timestamp = memoryinfo.Timestamp
```

Looks like you're trying to select from all 3 logs simultaneously, but ending up with another cartesian product. Are you sure you're getting the result set you're expecting?

Comment: Tested with print lines and you're correct that it's giving the error after I attempt the first select you mentioned. How can i pull all the data from all three tables if not this way?

  The second sql statement used to work when I had just "log" and cpuinfo", with no "AND memoryinfo.." and without the " = memoryinfo.Timestamp" so I assumed adding them in would just bring the next table in (i need to select them all at once to be in the same csv file). I added cpuinfo stuff in similarly and it worked.

Comment: If you just want `Process` from all tables, just do `SELECT Process FROM log UNION SELECT Process FROM cpuinfo UNION SELECT Process FROM memoryinfo` instead. See the edit above.

Answer (score 1):

You could limit the result returned by your SQL queryes with the LIMIT estatementet.

For example:

```
 SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 100
```

This will return the first 100 results

```
SELECT * FROM `your_table` LIMIT 100, 200
```

This will return  results from 100 to 200

Obviously you can iterate with those values so you get to all the elements on the data base no matter how many there are.

Answer (score 0):

I think your are loading too many data at the same in the memory. try to use `offset` and `limit` in your sql statement so that you can avoid this problem

Answer (score 0):

Your Java code is doing things that the database could do more efficiently. From query1a, it looks like all you really want is the unique processes. `select distinct Process from ...` should be sufficient to do that.

Then, think carefully about what table or tables are needed in that query. Do you really need log, cpuinfo, and memoryinfo? As Joachim Isaksson mentioned, this is going to return the Cartesian product of those three tables, giving you x * y * z rows (where x, y, and z are the row counts in each of those three tables) and a + b + c columns (where a, b, and c are the column counts in each of the tables). I doubt that's what you want or need. I assume you could get those unique processes from one table, or a union (rather than join) of the three tables.

Lastly, your second loop and query are essentially doing a join, something again better and more efficiently left to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Like others said, fetching the data in smaller chunks might resolve the issue.
This is one of the other threads in stackoverflow that talks about this issue:
[How to read all rows from huge table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682614/jdbc-how-to-read-all-rows-from-huge-table)