# Performance on number of rows retrieved from database

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm using Java JDBC connecting to a database to execute the query.

The query executes and it fetches million rows from the database. If I store this million rows in my array it causes memory issues. How can I limit the number of rows being fetched.

Comment: We can't help you if we don't have your code.


What you can do is limit your array.

Comment: One option is that you can limit the number of rows fetched. `SELECT * FROM tablemane LIMIT 0, 5` will fetch first 5 rows. Then you can process as desired.

Comment: Look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3682614/jdbc-how-to-read-all-rows-from-huge-table in particular setFetchSize.

Answer (score 0):

IF it is SQL - which it doesn't say, but I'm going to assume (reflex, I saw *dbc) - then there'll be a limit clause, EVEN Microsoft SQL (which is a laughable thing indeed) has a LIMIT clause.

For example `(WHATEVER) LIMIT 5` means only 5 rows will be output (or updated, or deleted, as limits may be used there).

`(WHATEVER) LIMIT 5,10` means 10 rows from the 5th row, so 6 to 15 if your rows start at 1.